# Rails: How to prevent unauthorized access of controller update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Hi I am new to rails and I am trying to figure out how to prevent unauthorized access to the update action of a controller.

I know I could have a before_filer that kicks out people that arent logged in and I have `redirect_to` in the `edit` action, but I want a way to stop a user from editing an object that does not belong to them.

Ex: A authorized user can simply change a `job` object in my app, by directly sending a `PUT` request with any `job.id` as a parameter and change any field they want.

Here is my controller:

```
  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])


    @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end
```

To try and fix this problem I tried to check in the `update` action if it the user was authorized and if they werent, i would redirect them to the index page.

```
  def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    if @job.user.id != current_login
      redirect_to jobs_path
    end

    @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end
```

But when I try to do this, rails gives me an error saying I can only have one redirect in an action.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the straightforward fix to your immediate problem is to use flow control to make sure that only one `redirect_to` is ever reached on a single request, as many others have suggested.

However, that's not really how I'd solve your larger problem.

First, there are a lot of existing solutions for managing authorization, such as [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify). I'd look into those.

Second, I'd use a `before_filter` to block access, as you suggest. Something like:

```
before_filter :load_job, :only => [:show, :edit, :update, :delete]
before_filter :require_authorization, :only => [:edit, :update, :delete]

def load_job
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])
end

def require_authorization
  redirect_to jobs_path unless current_user.can_edit?(@job) # or whatever you want to check
end
```

The before filters will execute in order, so you'll already have the user & the job available when you check permissions, and can check permissions for that specific job.

Answer (score 1):

```
def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    @job.update_attributes(params[:job]) unless @job.user.id != current_login

    redirect_to jobs_path
end
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because after the first redirect the second one could still be executed.
Thus putting the `update_attributes` and the second `redirect` into the else path like this should solve the problem:

```
    def update
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])

      if @job.user.id != current_login
        redirect_to jobs_path
      else
        @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
        redirect_to jobs_path
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do `redirect_to jobs_path and return` or `return redirect_to jobs_path`.

Try the following:

```
def update
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])

    if @job.user.id != current_login
      redirect_to jobs_path and return
    end

    @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
    redirect_to jobs_path and return
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use an Else Clause

The problem is that the [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html) method doesn't end the current method; it just tells the controller to set some headers. In order to prevent this problem, you need to make sure that control doesn't "fall through" to the second redirect. One way to do this would be to put your alternative path into an else clause. For example:

```
def update
  @job = Job.find(params[:id])

  if @job.user.id != current_login
    redirect_to jobs_path
  else
    @job.update_attributes(params[:job])
    redirect_to jobs_path
  end
end
```